Open Youtube links in Youtube PWA/App of Chrome for Windows
I installed Youtube as app (PWA) by opening the youtube website, three dot menu ... installing Youtube:


Now, if I click on a Youtube link through an usual Chrome tab I like to see it opening this app, but I can't find any setting for this.
I found this article for "link handling" of Edge, but something similar seems not to exist for Chrome:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps-chromium/how-to/handle-urls

Any ideas how I could solve this?
